# iphone development: speech to text and text to speech

Tags: iphone, objective-c, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, turkish

I am looking for an sdk for text to speech and speech recognition. There are many free sources but unfortunately they all are in English or other popular european languages. The thing is I am looking for turkish language. Is there any source provides it?

Comment: Turkish.. Have you tried Googling in Turkish then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my knowledge there are two API's which support Turkish language.

1. [**Acapela**](http://www.acapela-group.com/turkish-50-text-to-voice.html)
2. [**ispeech**](http://www.ispeech.org/apps/tts)

Comment: yes you are right but unfortunately both of them only supporting Text-To-Speech. However I also need speech to text.

Comment: @death7eater: for speech to text there are dragon( nuance ) and openears unfortunately both won't support turkish

Comment: @death7eater: also iSpeech supports speech recognition, please check http://www.ispeech.org/

Answer (score 1):

Please check this api. It have support for Turkish Language too.

http://www.ispeech.org/api

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I also saw it but I am not sure it supports speech recognition in Turkish. It is great at text-to-speech but I could not find any way to use its speech recognition feature for Turkish.